# IntelliJ always wants to show excluded files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1 (Build #IU-181.4203.550).  I prefer to NOT show excluded files.  So I un-check the "Show Excluded Files".  This works.

However, no matter how many times I do this, it always reverts back to showing excluded files.  Maybe not immediately, but after a few reboots or even after a few project loads, it's back to showing excluded files.  It's done this for as long as I can remember.

Is there a settings file somewhere or something I can do so that I never see the excluded files no matter what?  I'd like for that to be the default (and permanent) option.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use .ignore plug-in? Does the issue persist if you disable it? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189419 may be related.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that plugin.

Comment: The state of this option is stored in `.idea/workspace.xml` file. Check the history of this file to see why it gets modified.

Comment: @CrazyCoder hmm.  I'm not sure what could be changing that entry in that file.  I don't normally put my .idea folder in my repo so only IntelliJ should be changing it as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can permenantly ignore/hide files and folders using:
Settings -> Editor -> File Types
All the way at the bottom of this settings view you'll see a small text input with: "Ignore files and folders".

Now they should be ignored, excluded and hidden.

Never experienced any issues with this option.

Comment: FYI, I've been trying this method for a few days and it seems to work great.  Thanks!